# jQuery Regex to extract all HTML except br, bold, italic, and a

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, paste

I'm using an extremely ugly function in jQuery to listen on a `paste` event and remove all extraneous HTML formatting from the paste. Unfortunately, what I have now is overly strict, on top of just being butt-ugly.

I want to improve this regex to allow for the same HTML I'm already allowing inside the WYSIWYG editor. This means I would like to have `<b>`, `<i>`, `<br>`, and `<a>` tags allowed.

I do not know enough regex to do this myself, and would be very appreciative to see this improved.

```
$('iframe').ready(function() {
  $(this).contents().find('.wysiwyg').find('iframe').contents()
  .find('.wysiwyg').bind('paste', function() {
    var el = $(this);
    setTimeout(function() {
        var strClean = el.text().replace(/<\/?[^>]+>/gi, '');
        el.text(strClean);
    }, 0);
  });
});
```

You can see this ugly code at work here: http://jsfiddle.net/v4LhV/3/

Comment: Here is a fairly [popular discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) on the subject .. (*the gist of it being - you cannot parse (x)html with regex*)

Comment: Excellent comment. This really should be posted as an answer, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have a fully functional DOM parser, namely the browser, at hand, why not just parse the whole thing using [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) in to an element (off screen), then run through removing stuff you do not want using [`.unwrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/).

Comment: @John Smith, can you please provide the piece of work that solved your problem.  I am having the same problem.

Comment: @learning - It's Josh Smith, not John Smith you're after and best to post such a comment on the question itself, as this answer is more a suggestion of techniques than an implementation of them.  Of course you could follow the same suggestions...